CsvHelper.CsvReader won't read CSV file
first things first, my program is supposed to append the contents of a CSV file to an SQL table in SQL Server, using the path put into a text box "pathInputTextBox" and table name from a text box "tableInputTextBox" when you press the button "toSqlButton". After I'm done with this part I will also have it do so for different types of data bases using different buttons, but for now it already fails at reading the csv file. (I don't even know if it can even correctly append the data afterwards, but I am a silly lad that writes all of the code first and then tackles one problem after another, so I'll cross that bridge when I get there.)
The error is:
CsvHelper.ReaderException: 'No header record was found.  
IReader state:  
   ColumnCount: 0  
   CurrentIndex: -1  
   HeaderRecord:  

from the line
csv.ReadHeader();  

in the toSQLButton_Click event. By debugging I have found out that this is due to the method ReadCSV returning null, as it should whenever reading the file fails.
Among some of the things I have tried to fix this are writing different ways to read the file (e.g. TextReader) that would still work with a similar syntax and writing
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = true });  

instead of
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

but none of that seems to work. I am 100% sure that the file path I write into the Text Box should work (yes, I deleted the "s after copying it in the file explorer). I have sifted through the internet and asked ChatGPT for help but I am at my wits ends and it feels like it must be some very tiny, silly rookie mistake baked into the code somewhere that should be obvious. Please help me, I am looking forward to your responses.
The code:
private CsvReader ReadCSV(string pathString)
{
    try
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(pathString);
        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = true });
        return csv;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File not found. Please check the entered file path.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while reading the CSV file: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return null; 
}

private void toSqlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlConnection = "Data Source=VERYCOOLDATASOURCE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VeryCoolDB;Integrated Security=True";
    CsvReader csv = ReadCSV(pathInputTextBox.Text);
    using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        // Get CSV column names for comparison
        csv.ReadHeader();
        List<string> csvColumns = csv.HeaderRecord.ToList() ?? new List<string>();

        // Get SQL column names for comparison
        List<string> sqlColumns = GetSQLColumns(sqlConnection, $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableInputTextBox.Text}'");

        // Compare columns
        if (csvColumns.All(sqlColumns.Contains) && csvColumns.Count == sqlColumns.Count)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction sqltrans = sqlconn.BeginTransaction())
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, sqltrans))
                {
                    sqlcopy.DestinationTableName = tableInputTextBox.Text;
                    CsvDataReader csvdata = new CsvDataReader(csv);
                    sqlcopy.WriteToServer(csvdata);
                    sqltrans.Commit();
                }
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while writing the data: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Columns of the CSV file and columns of the SQL table do not match.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

static List<string> GetSQLColumns(string connectionString, string query) 
{
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            columns.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    return columns; 
}

The contents of the CSV file:
mitid; vname; nname; gehalt; geburtsdatum
5; bingus; bongus; 1223.23; 2010-01-01;
6; bongus; bingus; 1223.23; 2010-01-01;

Using the file path:
C:\Users\MALA\Desktop\AppendExcelTest.csv

Shouldn't you specify that ; is used as separator somewhere? It's not omnipotent

I was wondering that but he has it just have to scroll to the right in the code he has:   Delimiter = ";",

I already did with the
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = true });
but I guess I might as well leave that in the code

Maybe the line breaks are not standard line break?

@Brad If you could maybe elaborate a tiny bit? How would I make sure that it does read standard line breaks as such?

If I ever have to check the link breaks (or any hidden characters) I open the file in Notepad++ and go to View - Show Symbol - Show All.  Then I can see what the line break is in the file.

Thanks man, I checked, but yeah, seems to not be that either, all standard line breaks.

Wait a second: using (var reader = new StreamReader(pathString))         {             CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);             return csv;         } think about what happens when you jump out of the method

@siggemannen
?
Shouldn't it still just return csv when the method is called correctly? I also tried getting rid of the using, but it makes no difference.

It doesn't read the file until you call the methods, and by then the reader should probably be disposed, so it shouldn't be good me thinks

Fair enough, thank you, I'll get rid of that excessive using and close the reader before the return but the same error still persists.

Can you update the question with current code?

reader.Close();, you still close it, that's not correct IMHO. Are you using this lib? https://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/bulk_insert_csv.php perhaps try to just follow the code from there

Regarding your last request, about code improvements/quality, you should consider posting a dedicated question on codereview.stackexchange instead, which is more suited for that type of discussion.

@siggemannen Sorry for the late reply, I am using the CsvHelper lib, I did have a look over that code, however it seems like one would have to manually write what each column is into the code by that example, while my program is supposed to be able to read the columns of any CSV file.

Can you create a smaller, more focused repro that we can try ourselves? Otherwise your question will just be closed due to lack of focus/information.

According to the documentation you have to call Read before calling ReadHeader to position the CsvReader on something. See https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file "Read will advance row. ReadHeader will read the row into CsvHelper as the header values. Separating Read and ReadHeader allows you to do other things with the header row before moving onto the next row."

Slight detour....you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you posted is wide open to sql injection.

@julealgon working on it, although i'm not sure what exactly I'd shorten

@Ralf THAT'S IT THANK YOU SO MUCH, I'll be writing the answer to this question now, giving you credit.

Thank you @Ralf for helping me realise the problem in the comments!
The problem is that when using CsvHelper, you first need to have .Read() before .ReadHeader().

According to the documentation you have to call Read before calling
ReadHeader to position the CsvReader on something. See
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file "Read will advance
row. ReadHeader will read the row into CsvHelper as the header values.
Separating Read and ReadHeader allows you to do other things with the
header row before moving onto the next row."

-@Ralf
Silly me thought, that it would automatically read the file when configuring CsvReader, probably fooled by the namesake. But you have to of course read a line first by using .Read()
Here is the corrected code (all I did was add the line
csv.Read();

before
csv.ReadHeader();

)
private CsvReader ReadCSV(string pathString)
{
    try
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(pathString);
        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";", HasHeaderRecord = true });
        return csv;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File not found. Please check the entered file path.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while reading the CSV file: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return null; 
}

private void toSqlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlConnection = "Data Source=VERYCOOLDATASOURCE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VeryCoolDB;Integrated Security=True";
    CsvReader csv = ReadCSV(pathInputTextBox.Text);
    using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
    {
        // Get CSV column names for comparison
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        List<string> csvColumns = csv.HeaderRecord.ToList() ?? new List<string>();

        // Get SQL column names for comparison
        List<string> sqlColumns = GetSQLColumns(sqlConnection, $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableInputTextBox.Text}'");

        // Compare columns
        if (csvColumns.All(sqlColumns.Contains) && csvColumns.Count == sqlColumns.Count)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction sqltrans = sqlconn.BeginTransaction())
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, sqltrans))
                {
                    sqlcopy.DestinationTableName = tableInputTextBox.Text;
                    CsvDataReader csvdata = new CsvDataReader(csv);
                    sqlcopy.WriteToServer(csvdata);
                    sqltrans.Commit();
                }
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while writing the data: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Columns of the CSV file and columns of the SQL table do not match.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

static List<string> GetSQLColumns(string connectionString, string query) 
{
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            columns.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    return columns; 
}


This is a misleading answer based on your original problem. The correct answer is a combination of my suggestion and Ralf's. This won't work if you still close the reader before returning.

@julealgon I wasn't closing the reader until I misread a comment, editing the code to do so, that was when I assume you first read the question. It wasn't part of the original problem.

I see, thanks for clarifying then. I'm removing my answer in that case as it doesn't really apply anymore.
